# VB.net Formato erroneo al enviar DateTimePicker

Tags: asp.net, .net, datetime, datepicker, navegador-web

Estoy haciendo un programa en **.Net**, para automatizar la carga de datos en una pagina web (la cual no puedo modificar el código).

El problema sucede cuando envío la fecha a la web. Como se aprecia en el siguiente código, se debe enviar la fecha en formato dd/MM/yyyy (que es el formato que acepta la web), pero en su lugar envía el formato dd-MM-yyyy(con "-" en lugar de  "/").

```
 fecha = Form1.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Fecha").InnerText = (fecha)
        WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation = True
        WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```

Como dato extra, si muestro la variable "fecha" en un messagebox, se muestra en el formato correcto. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste enviando simplemente el valor, sin la llamada a ToString()?

Comment: Hola!, si, antes lo tenia directamente con value, pero siempre traia la fecha en formato long, por mas que tenga declarado el formato custom en el form1.

Comment: Prueba: `DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()`? (Si necesitas el cast)

Comment: Hola nacl, sigo con utilizando tu código sigo con el mismo problema de "-".
El tema es que dentro de la variable fecha esta bien el formato, por algún motivo se cambia cuando lo envío.

Comment: @CristianRaña por que tipo de elemento tienes en el elemento `Fecha`?

Comment: Es un datepicker

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pasa el CultureInfo.InvariantCulture como el segundo parametro, y va a regresar el formato que le des aunque sea un caracter especial:

```
Form1.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
```

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco mejor esto?

Comment: actualize la respuesta a ver si t gusta

Comment: y deja de estar de "hater" dandome votos menos naco

Comment: Yo no le dí votos negativos a tu pregunta. Si alguien lo hizo es porque quizas la respuesta que diste no está bien explicada, no tiene calidad o es incorrecta. Esa es la forma en la que SOes funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos! Ahora pasa bien el valor! Un saludo